# Need to paste a column from Excel into Powerpoint- how to paste so they are individual slides, not one

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a column of 50 in excel 2003.  I want to paste it into powerpoint but it continues to paste as 1 whole text box.  I need 50 individual text boxes.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you need any of the functionality provided by the text boxes or would the paste option for "keep only text" work? The "keep only text" option turns on bullets, but that's easily remedied by highlighting what you paste in and changing bullets to 'none'.

Comment: Their are no formulas/values in each cell.  Only text.  When I copy from excel and paste into a blank sheet into powerpoint (and choose Keep text only) it still pastes as 1 large text box as a whole, not as 50 individual text boxes.

Comment: When you say 'text box' are you referring to the editable area of the slide or is it actually making a re-sizable control inside the edit area of the slide?  Are you wanting each cell on its own slide perhaps?  Keep text only on my version of PowerPoint gives me plain text with each excel cell on its own line.

Comment: text box as in the editable are of a slide.  Yes, when I paste into PP it gives me each excel cell on it's own line--good, but it's in one large text box no?  For example, you want to copy the first line and enter that into a different slide--can you do that?  I can not. When I go to copy the first line it's not a unique text box but part of the whole 50.  Does that clarify it a little?  Thanks

Comment: That does help clarify. I don't know of a way to automatically split text into slides based on line breaks though.  The closest thing I can find is to use a hotkey (Alt + Shift + Left Arrow) in Outline mode for "promote" to manually move each row to its own slide. I can edit my answer with this, but it's not automatic by any means.

Comment: didn't really help but thanks for trying panhandel

Answer (score 1):

Do a Paste Special and choose EMF or WMF as the paste type.
That'll give you a graphic rather than a text box in PPT.
Ungroup the graphic and with any luck it'll turn into individual text boxes, one per line.